# Weird Arduino mega 2560 digital output behaviour

Tags: arduino

Basically I'm trying to make a custom servo motor but i've noticed that sometimes some of my digital output are outputting a weird pulse

[image]

I know for sure that the board works and it always happens even swapping boards.

```
//Functions
    void serial();
    void sense();
    void stabilizer();
    void stabilizer_Asta1();
    void stabilizer_Asta2();

//Motors
    //M24 - Gripper
    const int M24_IN3 = 34;
    const int M24_IN4 = 36;
    const int M24_ENB = 7;                                      //PWM pin

    //M0 - Base
    const int M0_IN3 = 24;
    const int M0_IN4 = 22;
    const int M0_ENB = 2;                                       //PWM pin

    //M2 - Asta2
    const int M2_IN3 = 32;
    const int M2_IN4 = 30;
    const int M2_ENB = 4;                                       //PWM pin

    //M3 - Asta1
    const int M3_IN1 = 26;                                      //26
    const int M3_IN2 = 28;                                      //28
    const int M3_ENA = 3;                                       //PWM pin

    //M4
    const int M4_IN1 = 40;
    const int M4_IN2 = 42;
    const int M4_ENA = 5;                                       //PWM pin

    //M5
    const int M5_IN3 = 46;
    const int M5_IN4 = 44;
    const int M5_ENB = 6;                                       //PWM pin


//Sensors
    //Position
    int Base_pos;
    int Asta1_pos;
    int Asta2_pos;
    int Brandeggio_pos;
    int Rotazione_pos;
    int Grip_pos;

    //New position
    int Base_newpos = 0;
    int Asta1_newpos = -40;
    int Asta2_newpos = 0;
    int Brandeggio_newpos = 0;
    int Rotazione_newpos = 0;
    int Grip_newpos = 0;
 
    //Pin
    const int Base_pot = A4;
    const int Asta1_pot = A0;
    const int Asta2_pot = A1;
    const int Brandeggio_pot = A3;
    const int Rotazione_pot = A4;
    const int Grip_pot = A5;

    //Selector
    char part;
  
void setup()
{
//Serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) {
        ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
    }
    
 //Motors
    //M24 - Gripper
    pinMode(M24_IN3, 0);
    pinMode(M24_IN4, 0);
    pinMode(M24_ENB, 0);                                        //PWM pin
 
    //M0 - Base
    pinMode(M0_IN3, 0);
    pinMode(M0_IN4, 0);
    pinMode(M0_ENB, 0);                                         //PWM pin

    //M2 - Asta2
    pinMode(M2_IN3, 0);
    pinMode(M2_IN4, 0);
    pinMode(M2_ENB, 0);                                         //PWM pin

    //M3 - Asta1
    pinMode(M3_IN1, 0);
    pinMode(M3_IN2, 0);
    pinMode(M3_ENA, 0);                                         //PWM pin

    //M4
    pinMode(M4_IN1, 0);
    pinMode(M4_IN2, 0);
    pinMode(M4_ENA, 0);                                         //PWM pin

    //M5
    pinMode(M5_IN3, 0);
    pinMode(M5_IN4, 0);
    pinMode(M5_ENB, 0);                                         //PWM pin
}

void loop()
{
    serial();
    sense();
    stabilizer();
}

void sense()
{
    Serial.print("Serial=");
    Serial.print(Asta1_newpos);
    Serial.print(" Deg:");
    Serial.print(Asta1_pos);
    Serial.print(" Raw:");
    Serial.print(analogRead(Asta1_pot));

    Serial.print(" Serial=");
    Serial.print(Asta2_newpos);
    Serial.print(" Deg:");
    Serial.print(Asta2_pos);
    Serial.print(" Raw:");
    Serial.println(analogRead(Asta2_pot));
}

void serial()
{
    if(Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        digitalWrite(M3_ENA, 0);
        digitalWrite(M2_ENB, 0);
        Asta2_newpos = Serial.parseInt();
    }
}

void stabilizer()
{
    stabilizer_Asta2();
    stabilizer_Asta1();
}

void stabilizer_Asta2()
{
    Asta2_pos = map(analogRead(Asta2_pot), 0, 1023, -135, 135);

    if (Asta2_pos > Asta2_newpos + 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(M2_IN4, 1);
        digitalWrite(M2_IN3, 0);
        digitalWrite(M2_ENB, 1);
        //Serial.println("maggiore");
    }
    if (Asta2_pos < Asta2_newpos - 1)
    {
        digitalWrite(M2_IN3, 1);
        digitalWrite(M2_IN4, 0);
        digitalWrite(M2_ENB, 1);
        //Serial.println("minore");
    }
    else
    {
        digitalWrite(M2_IN3, 0);
        digitalWrite(M2_IN4, 0);
        digitalWrite(M2_ENB, 1);
        //Serial.println("centre");
    }
}

void stabilizer_Asta1()
{
    Asta1_pos = map(analogRead(Asta1_pot), 0, 1023, -135, 135);

    if (Asta1_pos > Asta1_newpos+1)
    {
        digitalWrite(M3_IN2, 0);
        digitalWrite(M3_IN1, 1);
        digitalWrite(M3_ENA, 1);
        //Serial.println("maggiore");
    }

    else if (Asta1_pos < Asta1_newpos-1)
    {
        digitalWrite(M3_IN1, 0);
        digitalWrite(M3_IN2, 1);
        digitalWrite(M3_ENA, 1);
        //Serial.println("minore");
    }

    else
    {
        digitalWrite(M3_IN1, 0);
        digitalWrite(M3_IN2, 0);
        digitalWrite(M3_ENA, 1);
        //Serial.println("centre");
    }
}
```

Edit 15/01/2021: The issue is solved, i forgot an "else if" in the second stabiliser.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us *in the question itself*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `digitalWrite` on input pins. This will only enable or disable the internal pullup resistor.

I suggest you give the Arduino manual a read. Trying random things usually isn't too successful

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/

To avoid confusion it is usually a good idea to use Arduino's macros.

`pinMode(13, INPUT)` is obvious. `pinMode(13, 0)` is not.

From Arduino.h:

```
#define INPUT             0x00
#define OUTPUT            0x01
#define INPUT_PULLUP      0x02
```

All of your pins were set to pinMode `0` which makes them inputs.

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was the same writing 0 or OUTPUT (at least that's what we were told at school). Never had the chance to take a look at arduino.h tho.

Comment: @S1m0n3 https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Arduino.h    never trust your teacher ;)

Comment: I've changed the code right now but i can't try it until the 8th of January. I'll let you know if the issue is solved.

Comment: The issue is solved, i forgot an "else if" in the second stabiliser.